# P-values are uniformly distributed before batch correction but not after - is this a problem?

Tags: distributions, p-value

This may be a simple question but better be safe than sorry:

I have a genomic data set with two groups ("disease" factor). When I run singular value decomposition analysis I identify batch effects. Thus, I want to correct for these batch effects before I analyse my data with linear regression.
Before I correct for batch effects, my p-values are normally distributed as determined by a Q-Q plot. However, after batch effect correction my p-values are heavily skewed left, see picture.

I can't figure out if this is something I should be worried about? I have remarkable more significant differences than what I expected a priori, however, I believe this is do to stringent sample stratification.

[image]

Comment: (1) We would never expect p-values to be Normally distributed. It's theoretically impossible for this to happen and practically it is hard to see how it could happen, ever. (2) This does not appear to be a Normal qq plot: it appears to be an *exponential* qq plot for the *log* p-values.  It would be the equivalent of a *uniform* qq plot for the p-values, which is what would be expected under a null hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you @whuber for clarification!
Indeed, my data follow a non-normal distribution which has also been confusing me. It seems I've been mixing these terms without thinking.

So does I understand it correctly, (a) my data does not follow a uniform distribution; (b) I should not worry about the deviation from the expected distribution?

Comment: (1) The distribution of p-values says little about the distribution of your data. (2) Since the distribution appears to be strongly skewed towards smaller p-values (that is, larger negative logarithms), it suggests you have many groups of data that do not follow whatever null hypothesis you are testing. (3) It is striking that the square roots of your p-values are close to uniformly distributed.  That seems to deserve further investigation.

Comment: Does this suggest that my data are possibly inflated in some way? As I wrote above, I've already corrected for batch effects.

Comment: I cannot tell, because I'm beginning to suspect that we might be looking at some artifact of your correction process--but you haven't explained how you did that.

Comment: I'm working with EWAS data and I'm using beta values in the ChAMP package. [link](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/ChAMP/inst/doc/ChAMP.html) I'm using the Combat package [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/COMBAT/COMBAT.pdf) for correction for two factors that I identified as effectors using SVD analysis.

I'm also worried about an artifact from correction. However, I don't have any clue what I should do, therefore I'm reaching out...

Comment: If you would include that information in the post itself--preferably with a brief account of how that correction works--it might attract the interest of someone knowledgeable who can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference:
After batch correction with ComBat in the SVA package WITHOUT group information, no inflation of p-values was identified. The problem with the two-way ANOVA design in batch correction has been pointed out by Nygaard et al. (doi:10.1093/biostatistics/kxv027). As suggested by the authors, I chose not to use batch correction but instead included batch in the statistical analysis.

@whuber - thank you a lot for inputs on my problem!